# realloc вызывает исключение

Tags: c, память, динамические-массивы, realloc

Отладчик выдает на realloc-ах HEAP[buyerList.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00CD0000, 00CF3B58 )
пробовал приравнять через возвращаемое значение ( input=(char*)realloc(input,locatedMemory); ), но толку
у от этого не было.
В чем тут проблема ? Есть какой-то негласный принцип о котором я почему-то не знаю ?

```
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    system("chcp 1251");
    while (1) {
        int basedNumber = 10;
        char *input;
        input = (char*)malloc(basedNumber);
        int restOfSpace = basedNumber;
        int locatedMemory = basedNumber;
        printf("Введите команду:\n");
        //input[0] = '\0';
        char symbol;
        short cursor = 0;
        while ((symbol=getchar())!='\n')
        {
            if (restOfSpace == 0) {
                realloc(input, locatedMemory+5);//Вот на этом моменте программа вылетает, а отладчик пишет HEAP[buyerList.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00CD0000, 00CF3B58 )

                locatedMemory += 5;
                restOfSpace +=5;
            }
            *(input+cursor) = symbol;
            cursor++;
            restOfSpace--;
        }
        if (restOfSpace == 0) {
            realloc(input, locatedMemory);//место с аналогичной проблемой
            locatedMemory += 5;
        }
        *(input+cursor) = '/n';
        cursor++;
        input[cursor] = '/0';

        //код который работает с полученной строкой
        free(input);

    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> man realloc
```

The  realloc()  function  returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any built-in type and may be different from ptr, or NULL if the request fails.  If size was equal to 0, either NULL or  a  pointer suitable  to  be  passed  to free() is returned.  If realloc() fails, the original block is left untouched; it is not freed or moved.

Возвращает указатель на новый участок памяти или **NULL** при неудаче. В случае неудачи перемещения область памяти остаётся нетронутой.

```
char * newinput = realloc(input, locatedMemory+5);
if ( newinput != NULL )
  input = newinput ;
else
  fprintf(stderr,"Memory error\n");
```

И во втором случае тоже нужно не забывать добавить память. А то у вас `realloc(input, locatedMemory);` - вызывает вопросы, это-же ничего не меняет.